# Não consigo imprimir o atributo do objeto no log

Tags: angular, typescript

Bom,tenho uma classe:

```
export class Usuario{


private id : string;
private bluetoothMAC: string;
private cpf: string;
private nome: string;
private oficinaVisitadas: Oficina[];
private cacheMAC: Mac[];
private saidaMAC: Mac[];

constructor(){

}
//gets and sets
```

tenho esse metodo que retorna o usuario

```
getUserKeyMAC(MAC: string):Usuario{
let key: string = ""
let oMAC: string = ""
let rt: any;
let us:any;
oMAC = MAC
this.items = this.angularFire.list('/Usuarios', { preserveSnapshot: true });
us = new Usuario
this.items.subscribe(snapshots => {
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    let arrayTemp:any
    let aMAC: string = ""
    aMAC = snapshot.val().bluetoothMAC
    if (aMAC === oMAC) {
      us.$id=snapshot.key
      us.$nome = snapshot.val().nome;
      us.$cpf = snapshot.val().cpf;
      us.$bluetoothMAC = snapshot.val().bluetoothMAC;
      arrayTemp= new Array;
      arrayTemp = snapshot.val().oficinaVisitadas
      us.$oficinaVisitadas=arrayTemp
    }
  });
})
return us
}
```

e aqui onde eu recebo o retorno,tento imprimir qualquer atributo do usuario,mas vem como undefined:

```
marcaEntrada(obs:Observable<Mac[]>){
obs.subscribe(macs=>{
  macs.forEach((mac)=>{
      let us:any;
      us = new Usuario;
      us=this.hfb.getUserKeyMAC(String(mac.mac));
      console.log(us.$id); 
  })
  })
  }
```

essa e a saida:
[image: log]

mas se tento imprimir o objeto todo ele aparece normalmente:

[image: Objeto todo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está esperando o retorno que ainda não está pronto. A sua função getUserKeyMAC não conseguirá passar o retorno que você espera no momento desejado, pois ela é assíncrona.
Isso quer dizer que as linhas abaixo serão processadas sem nenhuma esperar pela outra:

```
this.items = this.angularFire.list('/Usuarios', { preserveSnapshot: true });
us = new Usuario
this.items.subscribe(snapshots => {// códigos aqui});
return us;
```

Com Angular e essa nova arquitetura de chamadas assíncronas você terá que mudar um pouco o pensamento sempre que fizer uma conexão HTTP ou algo que retorne um Observable, Subscribe, etc. Sendo assim, nunca espere o retorno no momento da chamada.

Veja um conceito de como você poderia adaptar.

```
getUserKeyMAC(MAC: string): Observable<Usuario[]>{

  // outras coisas aqui 

   this.items = this.angularFire.list('/Usuarios', { preserveSnapshot: true });

   return this.items.map(snapshot => {

    let us = new Usuario();
    let arrayTemp:any
    let aMAC: string = ""
    aMAC = snapshot.val().bluetoothMAC
    if (aMAC === oMAC) {
      us.$id=snapshot.key
      us.$nome = snapshot.val().nome;
      us.$cpf = snapshot.val().cpf;
      us.$bluetoothMAC = snapshot.val().bluetoothMAC;
      arrayTemp= new Array;
      arrayTemp = snapshot.val().oficinaVisitadas
      us.$oficinaVisitadas=arrayTemp
    }

     return us
  });
})

}
```

marcaEntrada(obs:Observable){

// A chamada do método ficaria assim

```
obs.subscribe(macs => {
  macs.forEach((mac) => {

      let us:any;
      us = new Usuario;
      let resultObservable =this.hfb.getUserKeyMAC(String(mac.mac));
      resultObservable.subscribe(usuarios => {

             if (usuarios.lenght > 0) 
             { 
             }
       }, (error)=> { console.log('ocorreu um erro', error); });
   }
}
```

Não vou dizer que isso é simples, não é simples, eu demorei um pouco para pegar a ideia, mas você precisará a se adaptar à esses tipos de chamada.

E a pergunta que fica no ar é, porque imprimir o objeto no console.log funcionou? Minha teoria é a seguinte, você imprimiu um objeto enquanto a chamada estava ativa e, como é objeto, as propriedades poderia ser muito bem alteradas ao longo do processamento, e foi exatamente o que aconteceu. Para provar esta teoria, ao invés de usar console.log(us), você pode usar console.log(JSON.stringify(us)). Isso mostrará pra você que o objeto está vazio.

Se precisar de ajuda para adaptar, poste aqui, ou crie um exemplo no plunker, daí fica mais fácil de auxiliar.

Comment: Entendi,eu estava tentando evitar o uso do Observable após definir o usuario,pois eu vou fazer varias validações e atualizações dentro do firebase com base no usuario retornado,o basico desse modulo em angular e inserir o horario em que o mac foi captado e atualizar ate a ultima vez que foi visto,isso vai demandar muito codigo dentro do subscribe,sera que tem problema?

Comment: Não vejo problemas, mas sugiro você que você, ao invés de colocar todo o código dentro do subscribe, chame o método dentro do subscribe. Desta forma o código fica mais legível. Exemplo: observable.subscribe(us=> this.tratarUsuario(us));

Comment: Mas neste caso o objeto estaria populado ou estaria controlado pelo observable ainda?

Comment: Já seria o objeto populado. Mas nesta situação seria igual o exemplo código que postei por último (o do resultObservable.subscribe), que é quando o objeto já está fora de observable

Comment: TypeError: resultObservable.subscribe is not a function

Comment: O uso da instrução sugerida vai depender muito do objeto contido em this.items. Por isto, o ideial para te auxiliar seria criar um caso no plunker. Se você estiver usando a lib angular/angularfire2 o **tipo de items** será **items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>**, como no exemplo da página principal. Talvez, esteja faltando importar algum pacote do rxjs, como Observable, Operator, Subscriber ou Subscription. O mais seguro é você investigar (console.log) qual é o tipo de items e os métodos dele. Importação de pacote: **import { <pack_nm> } from 'rxjs/<pack_nm>';**.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa tarde.

Você tentou usar dessa forma?

Class

```
export class Usuario{
    private _id : string;
    private _bluetoothMAC: string;
    private _cpf: string;

//gets and sets

get id():string {

    return this._id;

}

set id (id:string) {

    this._id = id

}
```

Função que seta os atributos

```
us = new Usuario;
us.cpf = "000.000.000.00";
us.id = "13449483890";
us.bluetoothMAC = "...";
```

Console log da Class Usuario

```
console.log(us.id);
```

Comment: já sim,funciona